# To use Google font

Tags: html, css

I want to use google font, Open-Sans.
I linked the font in my head in Home page.
To use the google font, this is it? Anything else?

Or, should I add 'font-face' in style sheet and generate font files from somewhere like 'font-squirrel', then save files in a folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to add

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

before the head closing tag, no need for fontface.

however you need to set the font-family: Open Sans in your CSS

Comment: you can add more weights in the URL
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: @phpmyadmin2014 It works on most of them, so basically supports the mainly used browsers, like IE, chrome, firefox, safari, and others.